# Import from excel to an access table with more fields (vba)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import-from-excel

I succeed in importing an excel worksheet in an access table when an user clicks on a button (by using VBA):

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet [Transfer Type], [Spreadsheet Type], [Table Name], [File Name], [Has Field Names], [Range]
```

I would to know if it's possible import excel data in an access table with more fields and if it's possible to process the excel data before they was inserted in the access table.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to an Excel sheet or range in a query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( ADate ) 
SELECT SomeDate FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]
```